# Certain Japanese Unicode String Breaks File Reading

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, cjk

In one of my programs, I regularly write wstrings to a file in c++ and then read them back. These strings are composed of Japanese characters.

I use this code to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

std::wstring readUnicodeFile(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream wif(filename);
    std::stringstream wss;
    wss << wif.rdbuf();
    std::string  const& str = wss.str();
    std::wstring wstr;
    wstr.resize(str.size() / sizeof(wchar_t));
    std::memcpy(&wstr[0], str.c_str(), str.size()); // copy data into wstring
    return wstr;
}

void writeUnicodetoFile(const char* myFile, wstring& ws)
{
    std::ofstream outFile(myFile, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    outFile.write((char*)ws.c_str(), ws.length() * sizeof(wchar_t));
    outFile.close();
}
```

I have used this code without problems for over a year. But today I tried to write and then read a specific unicode string "宴会".  The result is that it can write it but cannot read it. It only reads the first character and then cuts off the string.

You can use this to test it:

```
int main() 
 {
     wstring test1 = L"学校";  //Japanese word for school
     wstring test2 = L"宴会";  //Japanese word for banquet
     writeUnicodetoFile("somefilepath\\test.txt", test1);
     std::wstring s = readUnicodeFile("somefilepath\\test.txt");
 }
```

"test1" works fine the result appears in "s".  "test2" is broken and only the first character appears.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use the wide-character streams (like `std::wifstream` and `std::wofstream`) to read and write the wide-character strings as plain text?

Comment: And as a possible hint: You write the output to a binary file. Do you read from a binary file as well?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16

Comment: `会` is U+4F1A. On a little-endian machine that gets written to file as the byte sequence `1A` `4F`. And, on text (non-binary) files, 0x1A == Ctrl+Z == EOF marker. Hence @Someprogrammerdude ’s recommendation.

Comment: Including unicode character literals outside the classic ascii range (0-127)  ***in source files*** isn't a great idea. Your own IDE or text editor could be causing the issue by saving to a different encoding. Or in a team environment, it only takes one person to mis-understand how encoding works before they commit a change that corrupts these characters.  I'm not saying that't the cause of your issue. Just something to be aware of.  Use `\uNNNN` escape sequences when possible.